# Ways OpenDNS could be bypassed

Tags: networking, security, proxy, privacy, opendns

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro

Hello everyone,

I'm having an issue regarding some ways that people could possibly bypass OpenDNS's software.

I am testing ways of which this can happen, in order to learn the functionality of how someone could do so, and gain a better understanding of how OpenDNS works in general. I have searched the web for hours, but cannot seem to find any clear answers on its functionality.

I have read the following: http://www.wikihow.com/Bypass-OpenDNS-Internet-Security

and it would seem the DNS suggestions do not work, even after restarting services, processes, and even the computer itself.

Things I have tried (does not work):

- Changing computer's DNS settings to alternate servers
- Changing the MAC Address
- Setting a static IP
- Restarting Networking Services in Windows
- Using the "ipconfig /flushdns" command
- Restarting the computer after the steps above
- Any combination of the above

None of the above works, and some way, some how, this router is still able to filter certain sites out, despite telling my computer to use alternate DNS servers. **How is this even possible?** Does the router simply look up my computer's IP Address requests itself or something similar?

Pinging filtered sites, still returns the redirected IP.

Things I have tried (does work):

- Tor
- Using an alternate networking device (e.g. wireless card) (which is weird, because if changing the MAC Address doesn't work, why would this work?)

Things I have not tried:

- Messing with the HOSTS file (would this make a difference anyways if alternate DNS servers do not work?)
- Different Operating System (don't see how this could be related as far as DNS is concerned)
- Changing the computer name (same reasoning as above)

Any thoughts or ideas how a software can still redirect a user, given the above information? Any insights or information on how this works would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How have you determined it is opendns?

Comment: ""this router is still able to filter certain sites out, despite telling my computer to use alternate DNS servers" That's actually basic functionality in most routers to intercept DNS request and redirect it to their own. DNSCrypt probably works

Comment: @Paul http://welcome.opendns.com shows that it is configured.

Comment: @Martheen Thanks, Martheen, I was not aware of that functionality. I'll definitely take a look into that suggestion and post some results!

Comment: I seem to have discovered the "secret" behind these technologies: https://support.opendns.com/entries/22158370-Does-the-Router-DNS-overrule-computer-mobile-device-DNS explains that a router can force DNS redirection to the router's DNS, despite local computer settings, by blocking port 53 in the router. I believe this is what you were getting at @MartheenCahyaPaulo. But I'm wondering if a user could even circumvent this. I looked into DNSCrypt, but couldn't get it to work (needed compiling, was missing assembly references). What are your guy's thoughts on the port blocking?

Comment: You can't have the router relay DNS traffic if the router refuses to do so.  If the router wishes to capture traffic and respond in a way than relaying the traffic to the DNS servers you specify, the router can do so.  None of the options built into Windows will override that.  Options are: A) Alter the router's behavior, so it doesn't refuse to relay DNS traffic.  In other words, alter router's configuration.  B) Make your name resolution requests something other than standard DNS traffic.  A VPN can do this.

Comment: @JRenner I'm behind proxy right now (oh the irony) so I can't lookup more, but there are ready to use DNSCrypt binary floating around. Of course, it's also possible to just block nearly every port so DNSCrypt is also useless (such in my case right now), ISP can even do that.

Comment: @TOOGAM That makes sense then, since Tor would work. In my case, the router can't be altered.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo ah okay, probably should have done more digging with that haha. So it's capable of redirecting the port of which DNS uses then as well? Thanks for the info, I'll give it another shot. Do you know if it works by UPnP? If that's the case, no port forwarding should be necessary. As a personal note, see if Tor helps you out; it may or may not, but it's better than restricted access at least!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Martheen Cahya Paulo and TOOGRAM, I was able to find a viable solution a user could bypass OpenDNS (even if port 53 is blocked) by using DNSCrypt. Albeit this is a bit of a lengthy solution and requires some technical know-how, I'll do my best to explain the necessary steps. (Note: I took this route, as all pre-compiled versions I have found online seem to have been outdated).

Steps for this solution:

- Get the source code for DNSCrypt on GitHub (at the time of writing, is version 0.0.6)

  - Requires Visual Studio to compile
- Open the source code solution with Visual Studio, and de-reference "log4net" in the Code Project
- Download the library "log4net" and extract log4net.dll

  - Make sure it's the version compatible with .NET Framework version 2.0
- Copy log4net.dll to a subfolder within the Solution folder of DNSCrypt and reference it to the Code Project
- Build and compile the Solution
- Retrieve files Core.dll, dnscrypt-proxy.exe, log4net.dll, OpenDNSCryptService.exe, and OpenDNSInterface.exe, and put them in a folder somewhere you wish to store DNSCrypt
- Use InstallUtil.exe from a Command Prompt, with the argument for the assembly being OpenDNSCryptService.exe. This will register the Service in Windows.

  - A guide on how to use this can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(v=vs.110).aspx
  - Make sure to use the version for .NET Framework 2.0. Mine was located in: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
- Open up Services in Windows, find the Service OpenDNSCrypt, open its Properties, and on the Log On tab, make sure the radio button "Local System account" is filled

  - Reasoning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615367/windows-service-error-5-access-denied
- Right click the service, and Start/Restart it
- Go to the folder where you copied the assemblies from before that contained OpenDNSInterface.exe, and run it. It should now say you are protected.

I find it quite ironic that an OpenDNS solution was used for an OpenDNS problem. Of all of the solutions I have found, this seems to work best. I hope that whoever comes across this thread (administrators or users wanting privacy) will find this information helpful!